# change the text apperence using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

am new to angular js using this
ihave to perform following operation
i have a text name bob.and a button like bold and italic
while cliking on the bold button i want to bold the text BOB
and italic while clicking the italic button

here is the code

html

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="text" ng-model="rootFolders" ng-init="rootFolders='Bob'" >
          <button ng-click="chiliSpicy()">bold</button>
     <button ng-click="jalapenoSpicy()">italic</button>
    <br>{{rootFolders}}
    </div>
```

code

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {   

    }
```

[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aejvm/41/)

Comment: Read through this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/change-style-dynamically-in-different-ways-using-angularjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aejvm/43/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="rootFolders" ng-init="rootFolders='Bob'" >
 <button ng-click="chiliSpicy()">bold</button>
 <button ng-click="jalapenoSpicy()">italic</button>
     <span class="{{class}}">
         {{rootFolders}}
     </span>
      <br>rootFolders={{rootFolders}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.class=""    
    $scope.chiliSpicy=function(){
    $scope.class="text_type_bold"
    }
       $scope.jalapenoSpicy=function(){
    $scope.class="text_type_italic"
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.text_type_bold{
    font-style:none;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.text_type_italic{
    font-weight:normal;
 font-style:italic;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the directive [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Create two boolean, and set values when you click on the buttons. When the boolean is changing, the [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) is updating.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Aejvm/44/)

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-init="bold = false; italic = false">
    <input type="text" ng-model="rootFolders" ng-init="rootFolders='Bob'" />
    <button ng-click="bold = !bold">
        Bold
    </button>
    <button ng-click="italic = !italic">
        Italic
    </button>
    <br/>
    <span ng-class="{'bold': bold, 'italic': italic}">
        {{rootFolders}}
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}

.italic{
  font-style : italic;
}
```

---

*Reference*

- [AngularJS ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)
- [AngularJS ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)