# Is there a way to apply bold to selected text in textarea in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, textarea

i wanted to create a button that makes text area text bold. i used the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161630/change-the-text-apperence-using-angular-js) and was successfull in making text bold. But now i want to make the selected text only bold. Is there a way to do this.
Here is my code.
css

```
.text_type_bold {
        font-style: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }



$scope.textBold = function () {
        $scope.class = "text_type_bold";
    };

 <div>           
<button ng-click="textBold()" class="btn btn-sm"><b>B</b></button>
  </div>
```

```
    </textarea>
```

Comment: you want the text to only be bold when the user has the `textarea` selected? like this? `textarea:focus {
              font-weight: bolder;
            }`

Comment: No, you can't do it. For this functionality you need wysiwyg editor or contenteditable element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make text inside text area look bolder you can do that using simple CSS classes.

But if you're looking to format selected text only (bold, underline, link, etc), you will probably be better off using a text editor plugin. For example, see [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/), [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), etc.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ng-class directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <textarea ng-class="{text_type_bold: isBold}">Bob</textarea>
 <button ng-click="makeBold()">bold</button>
</div>

.text_type_bold{
  font-style:none;
  font-weight:bold;
}

var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {   
    $scope.isBold = false;
    $scope.makeBold=function(){
        $scope.isBold = !$scope.isBold;
    }
}
```

See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aejvm/117/

Comment: @Mircae this gives me what i already have.. i want to be able to selected b for eg in bob and make only that bold.. thanks